# HTML: Is it wise to manipulate static HTML during build/deployment to minify/bundle assets?

Tags: javascript, html, css, symfony, twig

I'm building a single-paged app with AngularJS and Symfony2 and would want to stick with plain HTML files to avoid polluting my views with server-side constructs (like Twig).  The plan is to minify and combine CSS and JS assets on build and deployment. To do this, I plan to create a console command that will:

- Read the target .html file and locate a pre-defined tag that contains
  the assets to be minified and bundled.
- Minify and combine the assets using native PHP, save it to the cache folder
- Modify the source HTML to use the minified/bundled version of JS or CSS

The HTML will look something like:

```
<html>
<head>
   <mini-me id="mycss" type="text/css">
      <!-- define CSS assets to be bundled/minified here -->
      <link href="content/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="content/styles/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </mini-me>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="main"> some content... </div>
   <mini-me id="myscripts" type="text/javascript>
       <!-- define JS assets to be bundled/minified here -->
       <script src="scripts/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="js-app/services/myservice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="js-app/controllers/mycontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </mini-me>
</body>
</html>
```

After the process, the HTML will look like:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="/_minime_/css/mycss14912900012301.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="main"> some content... </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/_minime_/js/myscripts14912900012301.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Am I running into a brick wall with this?